# Can Nami connect to custom testnet?

Tags: testnet, nami

I made custom testnet with magic 42. Cardano-cli work absolutly correct but Nami always connect to testnet with magic 1097911063 (main testnet).

So my question: can Nami connect to my testnet?

P.S. Yeah, I set custom node into Nami settings

Comment: Nami uses Blockfrost to submit transactions. If you're using a private testnet you cannot simply use Blockfrost to submit txs anymore. You'll probably have to setup cardano-submit-api in your custom testnet and tinker with Nami's local node setting (Network tab)

Answer (score -1):

Not at the moment.

But you can run your own instance of [Blockfrost](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-backend-ryo) and point your Nami wallet to it.